# Buscar ultimo registro firebase e incrementando no novo registro

Tags: firebase, react

Tenho a necessidade de buscar o último código em um array de objetos no firebase. Em seguida incrementar +1 nesse ultimo código e então salvar a lista com os objetos. Por enquanto criei um DAO genérico:

```
//Dao generico

'use strict';

findMaxCode: function(table, callback){
    var refFirebase = this.getInstanceFirebase(table);
    /* Aqui busca ultimo registro na tabela */
    refFirebase.orderByChild("code").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        callback(snapshot);
    });
},
saveOrUpdate: function(table, object){
    var refFirebase = this.getInstanceFirebase(table);
    var isSave = (object.code == 0);

    /* Aqui verificar se é para salvar/atualizar */
    if(isSave){
        this.findMaxCode(table, function(last){
            object.code = last.val().code + 1;
            /* Aqui atualize a lista de array */
            refFirebase.push(object);
        })
    }else
        refFirebase.push(object);
},
```

O que acontece ocorre após incluir o novo registro no array. Pelo o que entendi, ele está rodando novamente a lógica que consulta o último registro e ai acaba virando um loop.

Seria esse o caminho?

Answer (score 0):

Troque:

```
   refFirebase.orderByChild("code").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     callback(snapshot);
   });
```

Por:

```
 refFirebase.orderByChild("code").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     refFirebase.off();
     callback(snapshot);
 });
```

Assim, você pára de escutar antes de alterar o registro.

Uma coisa pra se olhar, é se once() seria melhor, já que ele lê o dado apenas uma vez.